# Inkscape ICC profiles location - specifically Adobe RGB color space

Tags: color, inkscape

I'm trying to figure out how to get Inkscape to use the Adobe RGB color space. In the menus I've found the colour management section in: File > Preferences > Color Management, and from there I can see in the Display Profile drop-down menu that there are some existing choices such as sRGB, Epson RGB etc, but I can't see Adode RGB here.

I've been told elsewhere that I need to install the Adobe RGB ICC profile in the correct director, then it will appear in this menu and I can select it. I was given the following link:

http://write.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/color-management/

In this article it states that for Windows:

.ICC color profile files need to be present in one of the following folders to be listed in the preferences dialog dropdown menus.
Windows (Inkscape 0.47+):

C:\Documents and Settings<user>\My Documents\color\icc

C:\Documents and Settings<user>\Application Data.color\icc

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\color\icc

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data.color\icc

application directory\share\color\icc

However I can't actually find any of these folders in Windows 10. I think the article is quite old and my understanding is that the Documents and Settings folder doesn't exist in Windows 10.

I'm at a bit of a loss what to do next. Basically I want to get hold of the Adobe RGB (1998) ICC profile and get Inkscape to allow me to use it as the Color Space. I've tried following the article in the link but I still can't figure out what to do. Does anyone know how to get Inkscape to use Adobe RGB as the colour space and if so how do I got about doing this? I'm basically thinking do I just need to download the Adobe RGB colour space as an .ICC file and place it in the right directory and then select it as the active colour space from with Inkscape.

Comment: Its your user folder. You can use %USERPROFILE% instead of documents and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape 0.47 is really quite old, so those instructions are probably outdated. Best to get the most recent version of Inkscape instead, if you haven't done so already.

The Adobe RGB (1998) profile can be [downloaded from the Adobe Website](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/iccprofiles/iccprofiles_win.html)

In Windows 10, extract the ICC profile from the ZIP you downloaded, then install it by right clicking it and choose "Install Profile". Windows will put the profile in C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color.

I just tried this, and Inkscape 1.0 can see the profile once it is installed at that location.

[image]